# Running Pyramid app in Jython + pserve (waitress)

Tags: python, jython, pyramid, pylons

I installed Pyramid, SQLAlchemy and `waitress` running in virtualenv on Jython 2.7 (platform: Linux x64). Unfortunately `pserve` cannot start:

```
% pserve development.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/bin/pserve", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 60, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 367, in run
    server = self.loadserver(server_spec, name=server_name,
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 409, in loadserver
    return loadserver(
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 255, in loadserver
    return loadobj(SERVER, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 269, in loadobj
    context = loadcontext(
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 293, in loadcontext
    return _loaders[scheme](
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 452, in get_context
    context = self._context_from_use(
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 475, in _context_from_use
    context = self.get_context(
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 404, in get_context
    return loadcontext(object_type, name,
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 293, in loadcontext
    return _loaders[scheme](
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 619, in get_context
    entry_point, protocol, ep_name = self.find_egg_entry_point(
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from waitress.server import create_server
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/waitress/server.py", line 22, in <module>
    from waitress.adjustments import Adjustments
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/waitress/adjustments.py", line 47, in <module>
    class Adjustments(object):
  File "/myapp/j1/ve/Lib/site-packages/waitress/adjustments.py", line 167, in Adjustments
    socket_options = [
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SOL_TCP'
```

Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: I'd guess Waitress does not support Jython because Jython doesn't implement necessary TCP/IP stack parts to function correctly. You can try some other Jython compatible WSGI server.